# SQL Multiple rows on output from a stored procedure without Cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

What I have to do is to print in output several rows from a stored procedure query without using cursors (if there is a way).
My database is about a video rental store and what I need to do is show a list of similar movies based on the genre of the given movie.
The procedure takes in input the movie name and what I have to print in output a list of movies with the same genre.

The table FILM is made like this:

```
Genre VARCHAR2(50);
Title VARCHAR2(50);
releaseDate DATE;
duration INT;
```

I already did it using cursors and it works, but I have to do it without PL/SQL, just using "pure sql".

I guess the right query to do this is the following:

```
SELECT title,genre FROM FILM WHERE genre = (
              SELECT genre FROM FILM WHERE title='Pulp Fiction');
```

This query is working if I run into the DB, but How can I have the same result using this query from a procedure?
I might need to use INTO for the SELECT and then I can't take a list of movies

---

I noticed that it isn't clear at all and I do apologize for that.
I've made a procedure for the Rent of a specific Movie.
I first check if the movie requested is available. If it is not, I want to print (via DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE...) a list of movies of the same genre of the movie selected.

I made this using cursors, but now all I want to do is doing the same without cursors.
I write down the code I made for doing this with the cursors:

```
-- DECLARATION
CURSOR CU IS
SELECT title,genre
FROM FILM;

-- LOOP ..
SELECT genre INTO genre_sugg
FROM FILM
WHERE upper(title) = upper(film); -- film is the input name of the movie

FOR row_sugg IN CU LOOP
  IF(row_sugg.genre = genre_sugg AND row_sugg <> film ) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Film: ' || row_sugg.title);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: It is not clear. Do you want a pure sql or stored procedure?

Comment: I apologize if it isn't clear. I need to use the query I wrote above in a stored procedure I already made.

Comment: But as I understand you do not want to use PL/SQL at all. Or do you want to do it just without cursors?

Comment: The "I have to do it without PL/SQL" is rather confusing then. Do you mean without explicit cursors, or without returning a cursor, or something else? Where do you need to 'print out' to; who (or what) is going to see and display the output? (Trying to figure out if you're looking for `dbms_output`, as an exercise...)

Comment: You got the point. I need to print the list of movies using the dbms_output...Let's just don't think about "dont want to use PL/SQL.." I just wanted to say that I need to do it without the use of cursors

Comment: @Guneli I want to do it just without cursors.

Comment: Do you want to print both title and genre or just title?

Comment: You have to have a cursor to be able to iterate over the rows and pass the values to `dbms_output`, but there's a difference between an explicit and an implicit cursor. What are you doing now, and exactly what are you not allowed to do - have a `cursor` declared explicitly (between the procedure name and the `begin`)?

Comment: @Guneli I want to print both title and genre

Comment: @AlexPoole What you're saying is exactly what i've done with cursors. Now, I'm not allowed to do is have a cursor declared explicitly. I edited the first post to clarify.

Comment: OK, then Guneli has shown you what to do. You should check out the [documentation on cursor for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) to see the difference between explicit cursors (as you have in the question) and implicit cursors (as Guneli is using).

Comment: @AlexPoole I think Guneli did the same I did (I edited the first post). Maybe I just didn't get that there is not a way of have multiple rows in the dbms_output...without using cursors (implicit or explicit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_movie(p_movie_name VARCHAR2)
AS

BEGIN
   FOR movie IN (SELECT title,genre FROM FILM WHERE genre = (
                          SELECT genre FROM FILM WHERE title=p_movie_name))
      LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(movie.title||' '||movie.genre);
      END LOOP;                          
END;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've already done. (I edited my first post). Maybe there is not a way to do it without using cursors (explicit nor implicit)

Comment: That isn't exactly what you've done; you used an [explicit cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#BABGJBEA), this uses an [implicit cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CHDBJBJE). You have to have something to loop over.

Comment: I got it. Lets say that I can't use FOR - LOOP ... Is it impossible to do what I wanted without implicit cursors ? Are those the only two possible solutions?

Comment: However thank you so much for clarified my doubts about implicit and explicit cursors. I assume this is the only solution for my problem. Thank you both of you again!

Comment: You are welcome! As far as I know, you have to use LOOP in any case to be able to print the list of movies.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a loop, unless you aggregate all of the titles into a single string and just print that single value; but you can avoid an explicit or implicit cursor with a table type and `bulk collect`:

```
create or replace procedure genre_match(p_title in film.title%type) is
type film_tab is table of film%rowtype;
films film_tab;
begin
  select *
  bulk collect into films
  from film
  where genre = (select genre from film where upper(title) = upper(p_title))
  and upper(title) != upper(p_title);

  for i in 1..films.count loop
     dbms_output.put_line('Film: ' || films(i).title || ' ' || films(i).genre);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This declares a type which is a collection of films, and a variable `films` which is an instance of that type. The [`bulk collect`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS1329) puts the entire results of the query into that collection. You can then iterate over the collection, instead of over a cursor.

With some simple made-up data:

```
create table film (genre varchar2(30), title varchar2(30));

insert into film values ('Crime fiction', 'Pulp Fiction');
insert into film values ('Crime fiction', 'Ocean''s 11');
insert into film values ('Crime fiction', 'The Italian Job');
insert into film values ('Science fiction', 'Alien');
```

The procedure shows:

```
set serveroutput on
exec genre_match('pulp fiction');

anonymous block completed
Film: Ocean's 11 Crime fiction
Film: The Italian Job Crime fiction
```

(Technically Oracle still uses a cursor of some sort under the hood to retrieve the rows into the collection, as it does for any query anywhere - in plain SQL as well; but that's unavoidable and rather beyond the scope of the question...)

Comment: That's a very interesting solution too. I'll study more about table types and collections. Thanks for the kindness, I really appreciated it.